# Explain about Entity key and Nullable propertys in entity model

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, silverlight-4.0

Can any body explain what is the meaning of below properties.

Entity key :True (OR) False

And Nullable :True (or) False (or) None

Comment: Let me know why i got -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Entity key**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee382820.aspx) defines whether the property is a part of the [entity key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee382820.aspx).

[**Nullable**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee382834.aspx) is one of the facets and specifies whether the property can have a null value.

For more about the **Entity Data Model key concepts** you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee382840.aspx).

Also, a lot of useful materials you can find here: [**Get Started with Entity Framework (EF)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907)

Comment: thanks for your reply. can you explain Nullable :None means

Comment: @Neeru-Bindela No problem! (None) means the default value is being used, which is "False" in this case.

Comment: Is nullable none always default to false, or it depends on the data type and relationship?